# What examples are there for grouping multiple site tools under one button or dropdown?

Tags: website-design, usability, interaction-design, buttons, dropdown

We're considering moving links to all our site tools under one button. Clicking the button would open a modal exposing links to these tools. The button would be in the header and be available on all pages:

[image]

The reason for this is to reduce page clutter and provide quick access to all of these tools. Has anyone seen examples of this? do you think this is a good idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen a few examples of this, and sometimes it was an improvement and other times it wasn't.  **It's one possible solution to a problem**, so without knowing your problem in detail, neither me nor anyone else is going to be able to give you a definitive answer.

Adding an extra step will clean up your page, but it **will result in fewer people using the actions that if they weren't an additional step away**.  Whether the overall impact is an improvement is something that you will have to test with your target audience or customers to know for sure.

That said, the button itself looks nicely discoverable in the navbar, and the way that you are displaying the actions (presumably when the button is clicked/tapped) is clean.

Once you do some usability testing on this (which I really hope you do), I would love you to come back and let us know what you discovered in the process.

Answer (score 2):

This makes the screen **cleaner**, but also makes the site tools **harder to find**.

Facebook started doing this a while ago, with the Log Out command and others moved into an anonymous top-right menu. After that, I noticed a few people on Facebook asking how they could log out, since they didn't know where the option had gone.

At first I thought that Facebook had made a blunder by making Log Out harder to find. But now I suspect it's a [**Dark Pattern**](http://wiki.darkpatterns.org/Home): people are more likely to stay logged in to Facebook if they can't find the sign out command. This makes it easier for Facebook to track people through Like buttons on third-party sites and so on.